# Can I accept bitcoin tips or donations in my free Android apps & widgets?

Tags: android, paypal, bitcoin

Is it officially allowed (or tolerated at least) by Google to do it?

I've got some users suggesting to me that it could be a good idea to add a one click 'donation button' opening up their default Android bitcoin wallet app with my bitcoin adress pre-filled.
But hey, I don't want to see my apps suspended just because of this!

Did you see some apps or widgets doing this yet on Google Play?

The same question could be asked about Paypal donations I guess...

Thank you to share your opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know what Google's official policy is for certain, but a donation should be no problem. In theory.

- http://play.google.com/about/developer-content-policy.html only mentions that any purchase of in-app benefits must be handled via Google's in-app billing system.
- https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html#pricing-payments says essentially the same in legalese.

So as long as donors do not *buy*/*gain* anything, not even a thank-you or honourable mention, and that is made clear in your app, you're in theory safe. Disabling ads for donors is for example easily a violation of those terms.

The rules are however Google's to interpret and enforce. And sentences like

> The Payment Processor must process *all fees* a Developer receives for any version of a Product distributed via the Store.

in 2nd link can easily be applied to donations if the app-review person sees fit, even just because he/she misinterpreted the donation button or

If Google decides that your donations are actually fees, they can & will suspend your app (probably without prior warning & time to fix the problem). There are cases of this you can find on the internet.

There is an appeals form you can find here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981 but the answer in practice seems to be ["No. Don't ask again."](https://medium.com/@joshliptzin/this-is-how-google-kills-your-app-c1abad30eb25).

Also be aware that Google counts violations and can [ban you as a person (not just your current account)](http://blog.hutber.com/how-my-google-devlopers-account-got-terminated-with-no-option-to-appeal/) from publishing apps on the Play store.

Comment: Careful, Google Play has suspended several apps (including my own) for having a PayPal donate button inside the app (even though it is not required / gives no benefit to the user) since they are not getting a share of the profits. It is against their Distribution Agreement. madhur.co.in/blog/2014/05/26/hermesremoved.html

Comment: https://play.google.com/about/developer-distribution-agreement.html#pricing-payments should not apply to donations. But having anything that could be seen like that obviously increases your chances to get wrongfully suspended, most likely because someone reported your app. And while your chances may not be the greatest, file an appeal https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2477981

Comment: I realize it doesn't address donations, and I actually pointed that out to Google in my appeal, but this is the exact reason my app was suspended, and you can simply search Google for "Violation of the paid and free provision" along with the word "donate" to see that multiple apps have indeed been suspended because of section 3.5 in the agreement you linked to. I think it's really unfair that they suspend apps for this reason, it would have been sufficient to ask the developer to remove it first.

Comment: @EladNava There are a few cases like https://www.marshut.net/kskuzu/free-app-suspended-for-adding-google-analytics.html that legitimately look like they consider donation a "fee" of sorts. There is maybe related http://www.reddit.com/r/androidapps/comments/212q22/google_play_store_suggestion_donation_button_for/ which roughly says that you can't accept "donations" because you're not a registered charity.

Comment: Yes, indeed they probably do consider donations as "fees" but the Agreement is very unclear on that and it is really unfair. I can only confirm that adding a PayPal donation button MAY get your app suspended without further notice. Here is another testimony: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/dZ2z6Hg9w_E

Comment: Please do not use donations in your app, neither with PayPal or Bitcoin. I had my application suspended twice because of a simple donation address where the user could donate if he wanted to in BTC.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is: NO.
You can't accept bitcoin tips or donations in your Android app, even it is free.
The same is applied for any kind of payment processor, including Paypal.
This because it violates our payments policy.

> **Policy Issue: Payments**
>
> Alternative payment mechanisms to Google Play's in-app billing service
>   are only permitted if the products purchased are to be used outside of
>   the app. For example:
>
> - For physical goods or services, such as movie tickets, or a    publication where the price also includes a hard copy subscription;
>     or
> - For digital goods that may be downloaded to devices and used outside    of the app, such as songs that can be played on other music
>     players.
> - Donations to 527 designated tax exempt organizations are also    permitted.

Answer (score -1):

Google don't have clear statement about this but i near future it's possible to allow it
[Source](http://www.forbes.com/sites/andygreenberg/2014/01/22/google-lets-slip-that-its-exploring-possible-bitcoin-integration-plans/)

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can. There are already plenty of apps that do this. On another note, for bitcoin donations, use the coinbase api. Its probably the easier in my opinion.

Comment: Do you have a working snippet of code of the coinbase api implemented in an Android app ?

Comment: I dont have a working example on hand, but here are a list of libraries there are: https://coinbase.com/docs/api/libraries There are no java libraries, so you might have to use json requests with: https://coinbase.com/api/doc One thing though. You will have to place your api key somewhere. DO NOT put it inside the app since people can find it. Put it on a server somewhere are make a call to the server for the address. I really hope this helps.